# Apply Checkpoint leaves the hyperv VM in stopped state on 2016 server host machine

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016

Whenever I apply a checkpoint using hyper-v manager (or restore to it using Restore-VMSnapshot cmdlet), the VM ends up in stopped state and I have to explicitly start it. This also means that all the process data at checkpoint creation time is lost. This happens only when the host machine is Server 2016. On Server 2012, the apply checkpoint reverted the VM to the exact state of checkpoint creation (so process level data was restored as well).
I have tried this with different host machines but all have same result. I don't see any errors in event logs as well (checked all hyper-v sources). Any idea what can be wrong here, why does the VM end up in stopped state on server 2016 host?

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Searching also for a soulution.

Edit: Change Settings from Production Checkpoint to Standard Checkpoint and the Problem is gone.